# tikz style to highlight upper case characters in label

Tags: color, tikz-styles

I would like to be able to highlight upper letters in node labels.  Ie my attached example I would like to see L and B in 'LaBel' in red and all other characters in black.

Is it possible to define a tikz style that displays upper case characters in a node label in red and all other characters in black?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    blocktiny/.style={rectangle,draw,font=\tiny}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[blocktiny] (node1) {LaBel};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I introduce `\hluc{}` in search of uppercase ascii to highlight.  It recursively calls `\hlucaux`, which examines one letter at a time of the complete argument.  When a capital letter is found, it applies `red` text color.

In `\hlucaux`, the code

```
\ifnum`#1>`@
```

tests for an ascii value greater than that of `@`, which immediately precedes `A` in the ascii table, and the test

```
\ifnum`#1<`[
```

tests for an ascii value less than that of `[`, which immediately follows `Z` in the ascii table.  The intersection of those two tests only tests true for capital letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\hluc[1]{\hlucaux#1\relax}
\def\hlucaux#1#2\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1>`@\relax%
    \ifnum`#1<`[\relax%
      \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \else%
      #1%
    \fi%
  \else%
    #1%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\hlucaux#2\relax\fi%
}
\tikzset{
    blocktiny/.style={rectangle,draw,font=\tiny}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[blocktiny] (node1) {\hluc{LaBel}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, ligatures will be lost in this process (though the `blocktiny` specification already does that), as will kerning between upper and lowercase.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\hluc[1]{\hlucaux#1\relax}
\def\hlucaux#1#2\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1>`@\relax%
    \ifnum`#1<`[\relax%
      \textcolor{red}{#1}%
    \else%
      #1%
    \fi%
  \else%
    #1%
  \fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\else\hlucaux#2\relax\fi%
}
\tikzset{
    blocktiny/.style={rectangle,draw,font=\tiny}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blocktiny] (node1) {\hluc{LaBel}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blocktiny] (node1) {\hluc{Ta}Ta};
\end{tikzpicture}
uc/lc kerning is lost

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node(node1) {\hluc{fi}fi};
\end{tikzpicture}
ligatures are lost

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[blocktiny](node1) {\hluc{fi}fi};
\end{tikzpicture}
but blocktiny already loses ligatures

\end{document}
```

[image]